# Influxdb data source in grafana shows "datasource is working. 0 measurements found"

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I try to use Influxdb as a data source in Grafana in order to pull metrics from telegraf (which is pulling from MS SQL).

On my Influxdb GUI I can see many measurements for the telegraf bucket.

[image: Influx DB GUI]

However, when I add it as a datasource in Grafana I get:
"datasource is working. 0 measurements found"

The details I enter for the data source are as seen in the picture:
[image: Grafana data source]

what could be the problem?